# random data insertion with primary key and key constraints Error Code 1062 Duplicate entry for key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

i'm trying to create a wine cellar database, with MySQL, for an university project.

```
create table Produttore(
    p_iva bigint(11) unsigned not null,
    indirizzo varchar(40),
    num_telefono varchar(20),
    primary key(p_iva)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Dipendente(
    cf varchar(16) not null,
    nome varchar(100) not null,
    cognome varchar(100) not null,
    indirizzo varchar(200),
    num_telefono varchar(20),
    primary key(cf)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Cliente(
    cf varchar(16) not null,
    nome varchar(100) not null,
    cognome varchar(100) not null,
    indirizzo varchar(40),
    num_telefono varchar(20),
    primary key(cf)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Bottiglia(
    codice bigint(8) unsigned not null,
    tipo_bottiglia varchar(20) not null,
    produttore bigint(11) unsigned not null,
    annata year not null,
    gradazione_alcolica decimal (5, 2) not null,
    costo decimal(5, 2) not null,
    primary key(codice),
    foreign key(produttore) references Produttore(p_iva)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Vino(
    codice bigint(8) unsigned not null,
    tipo_vino enum('rosso', 'bianco') not null,
    vitigno varchar(40) not null,
    primary key(codice),
    foreign key(codice) references Bottiglia(codice)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Spumante(
    codice bigint(8) unsigned not null,
    metodo enum('metodo calssico', 'metodo martinotti') not null,
    vitigno varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(codice),
    foreign key(codice) references Bottiglia(codice)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Distillato(
     codice bigint(8) unsigned not null,
     tipologia varchar(20) not null,
     composizione varchar(20) not null,
     primary key(codice),
     foreign key(codice) references Bottiglia(codice)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to fill each table with random data so i created a procedure for each table.

I filled the Bottiglia (Bottle) table, which has codice as primary key, but now that i want to fill the Vino (Wine) table (which is a child of Bottiglia, so it has codice as primary and foreign key)

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '81584254' for key 'vino.PRIMARY'

```
drop procedure if exists insert_vino;
delimiter $$
create procedure insert_vino()
begin
    declare c int; -- contatore
    declare var int;
    declare tipo enum('rosso', 'bianco');
    declare viti varchar(40);
    set foreign_key_checks=0;
    select count(codice) into var from bottiglia where tipo_bottiglia = "vino";
    set c = 1;
    start transaction;
    while c <= var do
        while c <= 175 do
            update vino
                set vino.codice = (SELECT codice
                    FROM bottiglia
                    WHERE codice is not null and bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia='vino'
                    ORDER BY rand()
                    LIMIT 1);
            set tipo = 'rosso';
            set viti = elt(floor(1 + rand() * 10), 'barbera', 'dolcetto', 'nebbiolo'
                                   ,'corvina', 'rondinella', 'sangiovese', 'nero d avola', 'syrah'
                                   ,'cerasuolo di vittoria', 'nerello mascalese');
            insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
            values(vino.codice, tipo, viti);
            set c = c + 1;
        end while;
        update vino
        set vino.codice = (SELECT codice
                FROM bottiglia
                WHERE codice is not null and bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia = 'vino'
                ORDER BY rand()
                LIMIT 1);
        set tipo = 'bianco';
        set viti = elt(floor(1 + rand() * 9), 'timorasso', 'pinot bianco', 'pinot grigio'
                           ,'soavignon blanc', 'friuliano', 'vermentino', 'pecorino',
                           'malvasia del lazio', 'grillo');
        insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
        values(vino.codice, tipo, viti);
        set c = c + 1;
    end while;
    set foreign_key_checks=1;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: a foreign key should refer to another column that is not the primary key

Comment: @nbk Actually, it's usually best for the FK to refer to a PK.

Comment: Primary keys have to be unique. You can't insert a second row into `vino` with the same `codice` as an existing row.

Comment: @BArmar read the create table again. his foerigen key refers to the primary key, which causes the problem in tbale Vino

Comment: @nbk Now I see what you mean. The FK *is* the PK of the same table, it also references the PK of `Bottiglia`.

Comment: The `vino` table should have a column `bottiglia_codice` that's the FK to `Bottiglia`.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st execution point where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation. A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Debug one software level or interface at a time.

Comment: @nbk i changed the create table for **Vino** and put as PK(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno), so technically now *codice* should be just FK in **Vino** table references the PK of **Bottiglia** table, but i stll get the same error

Comment: @GB99 post the new tavble designb it is not clear what you have changed

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Edit your post to the best presentation as of edit time. (But don't edit in a way that invalidates any reasonable posted answers or asks a different question than one you were trying to ask.) But again: If you ask about unexpected results, ask about only 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) case.